# Does ipython notebook 'run all cells' execute simultaneously or in sequence?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a code that is applying changes to a dataset and then the next cell picks this up to continue with an other set of changes. This is done for my own readability and troubleshooting in datamunging.

I think I finished the code and want to apply it to the initial data. Ipython notebook has an option run all cells.

My question is does it run them one after another or simultaneously ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very easy to see that it runs the cells sequentially. Simply change one cell to have something like

```
i = 39882
```

and in the following cell place

```
print i
```

If the cells would run concurrently, the latter cell would not print the value modified in the previous cell.

Answer (score 9):

It runs in sequence. You will actually see the progress as the cells that are in queue will show a star `In [*]:`, while the cells that have successfully will show some number, ex.: `In [123]`.